# Groovy - simple date reformatting

Tags: java, groovy

I am using the below code to convert `"Oct 09, 2018"` to `"20181009"`.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

def olddate = "Oct 09, 2018"
def date = Date.parse( "MMM DD, yyyy", olddate )
def newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date)
```

The problem is that I get the below output:

```
20180109
```

Irrespective of what date I convert the code returns the month as January (01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"MMM DD, yyyy` is wrong. Change to `MMM dd, yyyy`; `D` means "day of year", while `d` is "day of month".  See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html